# How to make gcloud app logs read tail mode start with recent logs?

Tags: google-app-engine, logging, gcloud

we are using GAE and we want to watch the logs live (few seconds delay is acceptable).
The `gcloud app logs read` command just returns the last log lines.

We wrote a little script that calls `gcloud app logs read` every 3 seconds and prints only new lines.

Is it possible to run the command in some "tail" mode so it will keep a live connection and print new lines as soon as they arrive?

Thanks

---- EDIT ----

@gregology, Here's my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
from time import sleep

def run(extra_args = None, min_cache_size = 50, max_cache_size = 2000):
    cached_lines = None
    cached_order = None
    cache_size = min_cache_size

    if extra_args is None:
        extra_args = []
    while True:
        while True:
            sleep(0.1)
            lines = subprocess.check_output(["gcloud", "app", "logs", "read", "--limit", str(cache_size)] + list(extra_args)).splitlines()
            if cached_lines is None:
                cached_lines = set(lines)
                cached_order = list(lines)
                continue
            if all(line not in cached_lines for line in lines) and (cache_size * 2) < max_cache_size:
                # None of the lines is in the cache - retry with a larger cache_size
                cache_size *= 2
                print "... google-logs-tail increasing cache size to %d lines" % (cache_size,)
                continue
            break

        new_lines = [line for line in lines if line not in cached_lines]

        if len(new_lines) == len(lines):
            print "... google-logs-tail log is broken - some lines may be missing ..."
            cache_size = min_cache_size

        for line in new_lines:
            print line
            cached_order.append(line)
            cached_lines.add(line)

        if (len(new_lines) < cache_size / 4) and (cache_size >= min_cache_size * 2):
            cache_size /= 2
            print "... google-logs-tail decreasing cache size to %d lines" % (cache_size,)

        if len(cached_order) > max_cache_size * 8:
            # much more lines than we need
            # keep only max_cache_size * 4 lines
            drop_lines = cached_order[:len(cached_order) - (max_cache_size * 4)]
            for line in drop_lines:
                cached_lines.discard(line)
            del cached_order[:len(drop_lines)]
        sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    run(sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Not yet, but it's very possible that we might add something like that in the future.

Comment: Can you please share your little script :)

Answer (score 0):

`gcloud app logs tail -s default` does what you want, I think.  `gcloud app deploy` suggests it.

Comment: `gcloud app logs tail` shows logs starting a month ago, it's useless :(